# 'sh: rake: not found' error when deploying with Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, capistrano

When trying to execute the command `cap deploy` from a Windows machine, I'm getting this error coming back from the VPS:

`sh: rake: not found`

If I SSH into the server itself, I can easily run `rake` without issues. It's in a weird location because I'm using RVM, but it still works. It seems like somehow the knowledge of its location is getting messed up when it's being run from Capistrano.

Agile Web Development with Rails adds the following to `deploy.rb`:

```
# adjust if you are using RVM, remove if you are not
$:.unshift(File.expand_path('./lib', ENV['rvm_path']))
require "rvm/capistrano"
set :rvm_ruby_string, '1.9.2'
set :rvm_type, :user
```

The problem is, I'm on a Windows machine (not using RVM), and that causes the whole `deploy` Capistrano task to crash because I don't have RVM. Do I need to have RVM installed locally for this to work? I would expect it's only necessary on the server.

Why the heck can't `rake` be found?! Sure works when I SSH into the server myself...

**EDIT:** It looks like this question is very similar:

[Capistrano fails to deploy to remote server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395411/capistrano-fails-to-deploy-to-remote-server)

However, his solution appears to involve doing the same thing I was trying to do -- except somehow he has no problem with the line `require "rvm/capistrano"`, which crashes on my machine. Also, his paths don't appear to be in the same format as mine?

Mine: `/home/sysadmin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin/rake`

His: `/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31dataserver/bin`

I'm really confused about how these environments work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duh, I didn't have the Capistrano RVM gem installed, so I couldn't `require "rvm/capistrano"` correctly. `gem install rvm-capistrano` fixed this issue.